# Submit when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#checkbox_evaluator_'.$tmp['employer_id'].'").change(function(){
if($(this).is(\':checked\')){
$.post(\'evaluation_ajax.php\',{op:\'forward\', 
id:\''.$request_id.'\', 
employer_id:\''.$tmp['employer_id'].'\',
responsable_emp_id:$(\'#select_evaluator_'.$tmp['employer_id'].'\').val() }
```

Please help, when you click on Checkbox, it sends an e-mail automatically. how can i change it to, only check the box and sendit with submit button. i'm new at Jquery so please be nice :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. Do you want it to submit when you check the checkbox? Or do you want to be able to use a submit button to submit it, only when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: thats right i want to submit when you check the checkbox, it is when checkbox is checked sends e-mail automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#checkbox_evaluator_'.$tmp['employer_id'].'").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(\':checked\')){
      $.post(\'evaluation_ajax.php\',{op:\'forward\', 
        id:\''.$request_id.'\', 
        employer_id:\''.$tmp['employer_id'].'\',
        responsable_emp_id:$(\'#select_evaluator_'.$tmp['employer_id'].'\').val() 
      });
    }
 });
```

Comment: it is when checkbox is checked sends e-mail automatically, i want to use submit button

Comment: In that case you can trigger the click event of submit button when checkbox is checked.

Comment: not sure how to do that:) i tried added a submit button, changed the code around but no results

Comment: try something like this $("submitButtonSelector").trigger("click");

Comment: you mean instead of $("#checkbox_evaluator_").click(function) ?